# How can I prioritize one form over another without hiding it in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

I've been trying to find a way to disable a form, and put another form in front of it to act as a receiving party for my update command from SQL Server. My only problem is... The appearance of my main form, seems to be simple, and I'd rather keep it that way. I got two exhibits, since I can't post pictures in this state yet... But I'll update so more will understand.

**Exhibit 1**: My ***medical records*** form has several buttons, containing the **INSERT**, **UPDATE**, **DELETE**, **View** via Crystal Report, **Print**, **Search** and the **Back** buttons. There's also a listview object placed that occupies most of the form.

**Exhibit 2**: My ***UPDATE*** form is consisted of 7 textboxes: 6 containing basic info, and one containing the full name of the user which is by default, read-only. Two buttons, **UPDATE** and **Back** are in the form as well. Labels are placed above the basic info textboxes to signal the user's information to be entered.

Here's my question: ***How will I disable all buttons and the listview*** (which is the form of Exhibit 1), ***and place Exhibit 2 over it, WITHOUT hiding Exhibit 1?***

*To clarify, Exhibit 1 cannot be accessed as long as Exhibit 2 is in place, once it's open (which is my goal). I was trying to find a way to put the Update form over the medical records form, but to no luck, I keep seeing the Medical Records form clickable once the two are open at the same time. Please help me out... I'm just a student who's getting the hang of things in Visual Studio 2010, but I thought of asking just to know if anyone knows.*

To those who would answer... thank you. :) It's my first post... so please be patient...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example which uses a main form `mainForm` and a button `cb_update` to open a second form `updateForm`. Upon opening, the 2nd form places itself over the 1st form and disables all controls of the 1st form. When it is closed it hides itself and re-enables all controls of the 1st form.

Note: both forms have a reference to each other, so they can work with all (public) parts of the other form. (If you need to you can always make a Control public!). One reference is kept from opening, the other is handed in the constructor..

En- or Disabling the controls is done recursively using the `Controls` collection and the fact that a `Form` is a `Control`, too. Here is code for the 1st form:

```
public partial class mainForm : Form
{

    updateForm Uform;

    private void cb_update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Uform == null)  Uform = new updateForm(this);
        Uform.Show();
    }
}
```

And here the 2nd:

```
public partial class updateForm : Form
{

    mainForm main_Form;

    public updateForm(mainForm main)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        main_Form = main;
    }

    private void updateForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Size = main_Form.Size;
        this.Location = main_Form.Location;
        //*1*
        setControlState(main_Form, false);
    }

    private void cb_back_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        setControlState(main_Form, true);
        this.Hide();
    }

    private void updateForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        setControlState(main_Form, true);
        this.Hide();
    }

    //*2*
    public void setControlState(Control Ctl, bool enabled)
    {
        //*3*
        foreach (Control c in Ctl.Controls) setControlState(c, enabled);
        Ctl.Enabled = enabled;
        //*4*
    }
}
```

**Edit:** This code assumes that all Controls on the main_form are initially enabled. If that is not the case an exceptions list will take care of that, adding four lines of code:

```
exceptions.Clear();  //*1*
List<Control> exceptions = new List<Control>(); //*2*
if (!enabled && !Ctl.Enabled) exceptions.Add(Ctl);  //*3*
if (enabled && exceptions.Contains(Ctl)) Ctl.Enabled = false;  //*4*
```

**Edit 2:** I am still not quite sure, what you mean by *"Place Exhibit 2 over it, WITHOUT hiding Exhibit 1"*. If you mean *"place it **above** without hiding it"*  1 or 2 lines of the code would be a **little** different.. Please explain!

Comment: That's right! Thanks for the reminder! I was thinking of placing the 2nd form over the first one, and making sure the first is not accessed, unless the second is closed. I didn't know they weren't the same, so thank you again! (Boy, I need a little practice...)

Anyway, you said I have to make both forms public?

Comment: _you said I have to make both forms public?_ If you want to access form1 (to disable it) form2 needs a reference to it; not public, though. If you want to access a control on the other form directly it should be public.

Comment: Are you implying a control on form1 should be public first before form2 will be able to access it? Or is it the other way around?

Comment: Yes, and yes. All `Controls` you drop on a form are by default private. So, if you want to set, say a label `Status.Text` in the other form you would have to make it public first in the designer.cs file; or you could access it via the form's (public) Controls collection Property like this: `otherform.Controls["Status"].Text = "done";`

Comment: Nothing else I can do to make a control public in a form?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with editing the designer.cs file. But you can also, as a 3rd option, create and assign a public reference for each control that needs to be accessed from the other form; declare e.g. a class variable `public DataGridView DGV = dataGridView1;` and then access it from form2.

Comment: Okay... I've been thinking about it... Can you please help me locate the cs file and open it? From there, I can take over.

Comment: Look at the Solution exporer! There are four entries for each Form: The code file (Form.cs), the resource (Form1.resx), the designer file (Form1.Designer.cs) and the entry which opens ther designer.  The  Designer.cs contains the code the designer creates when you work with it. At the end are the declarations of all the Controls. You can change to public what you need to access.. Be carful to to mess up the other parts!

Comment: I'll update you on what happens... Thanks. I've asked other groupmates to have an alternative to use only one form, but I'll work on this one... :) Thank you again.